# Windows Server 2012 R2 VM Box Change resulted in public network

Tags: networking, domain, windows-server-2012

I have a domain controller, AD2, which was operating as a VM on another server (one that uses Microsoft Hyper-V). I am in the process of porting to our new virtualization server (uses EuroNAS eEVOS). AD2 is now up on the new box and down on the old hyper-visor.

The problem is that I receive the infamous "public" network, even though AD2 uses a static IP address. Yes, I can see other IPs on the network and I can ping that IP.

I did a [search](https://serverfault.com/questions/639088/how-do-i-make-a-connection-private-on-windows-server-2012-r2) on the internet and came up with this Power Shell script, which worked for a few minutes but then after a reboot I am back to `public` `unidentified network`.

```
PS C:\>$Profile = Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Ethernet1

PS C:\>$Profile.NetworkCategory = "Private"

PS C:\>Set-NetConnectionProfile -InputObject $Profile
```

Using `gpedit.msc` does not work, as the method to `Show Networks` works for a client, not a domain controller.

I also thought of removing from the domain, but that works for a client. I got the message about demotion and whatnot. I did not want to cause more harm, so I thought that I ask first.

The VM part is immaterial, more that I changed hardware or box or whatever and now it is confused. With a client PC, I would remove from the domain and then add it back to get the trust relationship issue resolved, but we are talking about one of the two `Active Directory` boxes. The other one, AD1 is our DHCP server, thankfully.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is replication working between the two DC's? I'm thinking that may have something to do with it working then not working.  And what about kerboros, do the two DC's maintain an encrpyted channel?  Last thought, I don't see the harm in demoting AD2 then promoting it. Did you say there was some risk involved in that?

Comment: @Larryc I guess not, as I can take a snapshot first, just I am not the world's biggest expert. I do not do demotions and promotions day in and day out. Maybe that is the ticket, as Scotty would say.

Comment: @Larryc I was no allowed to demote the server as it could not contact any domain controllers (public network thing). The option to move to a workgroup was grayed out too.

Comment: One other thought, if the NLA comes up  to quickly(new hardware) then it may try to figure out where it is before the domain comes up. Try stopping the NLA service, count to ten and restart it. if that works, then set the service to delayed start.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, since its a VM you probably don't have multiple Nics configured, but try turning of ipv6, if your router doesn't support it then this can happen. There's a great web page on  the NLA i'll see if I can find it again.